# FindFirstFile causes "There is no disc in the drive" Error

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, findfirst

FindFirstFile function is causing "There is no disc in the drive. Please insert a disc into drive" Error. The cause of this error is that there is no sd-card in the USB stick and it's empty. My problem is that I have to scan all the drives for a specific directory and I cannot distinguish whether the drive is empty or not. How can I do this?

I am developing application for Windows and I am using MFC for development.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Farooq-

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing a little, but I suspect you need to call [`SetErrorMode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing the `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` flag to suppress this dialog appearing. Instead `FindFirstFile()` will return a failure code and you can move on to the next drive in the enumeration.

Edit:  For Windows 7 and up, consider [`SetThreadErrorMode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  That limits the effect of the mode.  Also remember to restore the original mode as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been a great help.